# Can an endpoint in AWS Lambda function call other endpoints in the same function?

Tags: aws-lambda

I have a controller in a jar which has 2 endpoints. I call one of the endpoints and it calls the other one. This is working perfectly in my local environment. However, the first endpoint gets called but it is unable to trigger the second endpoint in the AWS Lambda function. There is no error in the CloudWatch logs. What am I missing? Thanks!